# 2 белых IP разделить по портам mikrotik

Tags: mikrotik, routeros

В роутер приходит по одному проводу 2 белых IP, например: 100.100.100.100, 150.150.150.150.
Возможно ли сделать так чтобы обмен трафиком по адресу 100.100.100.100 выполнялся на портах ether2, ether3, wlan1, wlan2, а 150.150.150.150 менялся трафиком через ether4 и ether5?

Mikrotik hAP ac2
RouterOS v6.49.6

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите, чтобы клиенты, подключенные к одним портам, выходили в Интернет под одним адресом, а к другим - под вторым адресом? Два NAT-правила с указанием action=src-nat и нужного адреса в to-addresses вам помогут. Если у вас все порты объединены в бридж - можете создать два интерфейс-листа с соответствующими интерфейсами и указать их в правилах NAT как In Interface Bridge Port.

Comment: Пока проблема состоит в том что провайдер выдает 2 ip по DHCP с привязкой к моим MAC по одному проводу, а на физический порт нельзя назначить 2 MAC адреса или удалить его. А если за портом стоят 2 моста с зарегистрированными MAC адресами, то когда я ставлю один из зарегистрированных MAC на порт, MAC адреса бриджей игнорируются абсолютно.

Comment: Про мосты ничего не понял, но второй мак (и адрес, соответственно) вы можете получить, создав на ethernet-интерфейсе интерфейс VRRP. Соответственно, DHCP-клиенты на ether и vrrp получат каждый свой адрес.